# Api Gateway (Regional) + Cloudfront return HTTP/2 403

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

If it is a test stage (in Api Gateway) I would like to be able to add the stage name explicitly to the url or remove from the api call. Both should hit the stage environment.

1. Setup a *regional* rest API Gateway
2. Configured GET method /test/v1/health (test is stage name)
3. Deployed API

   - I can access it using the URL https://.execute-api..amazonaws.com/test
   - I can make calls to *https://**api-id**.execute-api.**region**.amazonaws.com/test/v1/health* and it is all good
4. Setup a *regional* custom domain api.example.com

   - Added a *Base Path Mappings* */v1* to **test** environment. Basically I would like to call *https://api.example.com/v1/health* since I want to have multiple stages but I don't want to specify test environment in the url. This should be optional.
5. Created a Cloudfront distribution and setup the origin to be the regional custom domain such as *d-**api-id**.execute-api.**region**.amazonaws.com* (note the *d* since this is regional) and *Origin Path* blank.
6. Updated my external DNS CNAME to map *api.example.com* to the *cloudfront* address.
7. Try to call *https://api.example.com/v1/health* and I get an HTTP 403.

Not sure what is going wrong here. Any ideas how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure the CloudFront distribution's Cache Behavior settings to whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin?  There is a better way to set this up, but based on the rest of your configuration, that whitelisting setting is probably necessary.  Seeing the headers and body of the 403 error would also be helpful.

Comment: I only whitelisted the *Authorization* header only. Let me try to whitelist *Host* now.

Comment: That worked @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: I found that I can live without the custom domain name in Api Gateway, and have Cloudfront do all the work. Since Api Gateway uses SNI, if we send the `Host` then this should cause issues. I opted to have Cloudfront -> Api Gateway -> VPCLink -> Backend API server.

Comment: Exactly! That's what I had in mind when I said *"there is a better way to set this up"* but I didn't want to throw too much detail at you in comments, since your overall config wasn't technically "wrong" except for the fact that API Gateway needed to see a `Host` header matching the custom domain.  Would you like me to summarize the alternatives in an answer, here?

Comment: It works when I deploy to one stage only, but if I have two stages in Api Gateway then create two origin domains + path in CloudFront to `<id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/stage-name` where `stage-name` is prod and dev. Now, when I create `Behavior Path` for prod it works fine. If I create another `Behavior Path` and set the root call to be prefixed with `dev/*` then I get forbidden. Really thought this was simple such that I can have multiple stages and if the stage-name is not part of the api call then send to prod, else if the stage-name matches `dev/*` send to dev deploy in api gw.

Comment: Not sure what the best way or best practice to be able to integrate Cloudfront with Api Gateway to be able to use the gateway's stage deployment feature. Please summarize the alternatives. @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, Will you please post your answer as well, going through the same problem.